# Tanzania Life Table

Tags: data-request, research, demographics, africa

I am doing a survey on Life Tables of several countries and I can't seem to find that of Tanzania for all ages (not in ranges like it is in WHO website) . Does anyone know where it can be obtained?

Answer (score 1):

[Tanzania Life Table 2013](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/191484_f1f4ea945ae0413d96ed18e95985e736.html)

data collected from UNICEF website “State of the World children 2015 Tanzania Statistical table”

Answer (score 0):

You could find life tables here: https://www.mortalitytrends.org/